# Using nextjs middleware with a statically generated page

Tags: next.js

I have a few 1000 statically generated pages in my app using getstaticprops. I want to conditionally render one part of the page depending on if the user was referred to one of these pages from an external domain - e.g. by using the referer property in the request header.

The docs say:

```
getStaticProps does not have access to the incoming request (such as query parameters or HTTP headers) as it generates static HTML. If you need access to the request for your page, consider using Middleware in addition to getStaticProps.
```

I've got a middleware.ts file to put the referrer in the response header:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  const referer = requestHeaders.get('referer');
 
  const response = NextResponse.next();
 
  response.headers.set('referer', referer);
  return response;
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/events/:path*',
  }
```

My issue is that I can't figure out how to access this in the static page file. I use getstaticprops to render at build time, but was hoping I could use the next/headers component. When I tried that I got:

```
You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.
```

Is there another way to access the response header? I'm using Next 13, but still in the pages folder.